# Getting error msg while updating a form of regular expression [a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+

Tags: asp.net

When I have to update my aspx.net form ..I got the error message that incalid code ,,,the regular expression is used is [a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+ if I remove the expression ...update is performed...kindly reply what is the solution

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="style19" Width="239px" BorderColor="#006600" BorderStyle="Solid" ForeColor="#009900"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Invalid Code" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server"

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="style19" Width="239px" 

                    BorderColor="#006600" BorderStyle="Solid" ForeColor="#009900"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" 

                    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Invalid Code" ForeColor="Red" 

                    ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            </td>

Comment: ok  but i need sollution to this

Comment: delete your validator and you don't need validator and you can validate your datas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter value to TextBox2, you must just respect this expression on your validator

[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+

If you don't respect you can't validate your data

If you want disable, you must just delete your validator

Replace with this code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="style19" Width="239px" BorderColor="#006600" BorderStyle="Solid" ForeColor="#009900"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1636962

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unintelligible. Where is the error message coming from? How are you updating your form? Where is the regular expression being applied, and to what?

Comment: i have a aspx form with 5 text boxes ,,the regular expression i used to validate the text enterd in the text box,,if it matchhes to the expresssion [a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+ data base will be updated,,but i m getting erro rwhile updating the data is enterd in the correct manner..